# How to make lambda support spring boot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

**Target**: I have a spring boot application and I want to make it work with lambda.
**Meaining**:  I want to create a jar that can be uploaded to a lambda function and when I call it with API Gateway it will return the same result as I run it on my computer with `java -jar`.

I have a `@RestController` and I created a class called: `StreamLambdaHandler.java` which should handle the lambda part.

```
package mypackage;

import com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyRequest;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyResponse;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(MyClass.class); // MyClass is the class where I do SpringApplication.run for my app
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could initialize Spring framework", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

I use its `handleRequest` function as the entry point for the lambda function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXht0.png)

I tried to do it with SAM. My saml.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'                                                       
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: AWS Serverless Spring Boot API - Spring Boot API PrycePick
Resources:
  SpringbootSampleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler:  pryce_pick.search.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java11
      CodeUri: out/artifacts/myfunction/my.zip
      MemorySize: 512
      Policies: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: any

Outputs:
  SpringbootSampleApi:
    Description: URL for application
    Value: !Sub 'https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/'
    Export:
      Name: SpringbootApp
```

I ran the commands:
`aws cloudformation package --template-file sam.yaml --output-template-file output-sam.yaml --s3-bucket mybucket`
`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file output-sam.yaml --stack-name bookApi --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`
Up till now, I did everything by guidance of multiple manuals.
Created the jar with all dependencies, and got to the test of lambda function in the amazon ui.
I got this result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STZDy.png) which seems to say that everything is ok.
BUT when I open the context I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RVNb.png)
Which obviously says that somethings wrong, and the fact that it doesn't work says it to :)
In addition there's a log:

```
ationTypeMapping.java:102)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.addIfPossible(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:112)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.addIfPossible(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:105)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.addMetaAnnotationsToQueue(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:99)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.addAllMappings(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:79)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.<init>(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:68)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.<init>(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:46)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.createMappings(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:245)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings$Cache.get(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:241)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:199)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:182)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationTypeMappings.forAnnotationType(AnnotationTypeMappings.java:169)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations$IsPresent.doWithAnnotations(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:330)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations$IsPresent.doWithAnnotations(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:279)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:188)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClassHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:171)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processClass(AnnotationsScanner.java:106)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.process(AnnotationsScanner.java:86)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:77)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.scan(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:242)
at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.isPresent(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:98)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:144)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:132)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:52)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:163)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:198)
at mypackage.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:29)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:375)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:899)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:262)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:199)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.main(AWSLambda.java:193)
END RequestId: 29d504dc-3510-4d78-b010-3fe48a4e6f13
REPORT RequestId: 29d504dc-3510-4d78-b010-3fe48a4e6f13  Duration: 2278.06 ms    Billed Duration: 2279 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 106 MB Init Duration: 940.24 ms
```

If someone have some insight about the process and what I am doing wrong please share. Even more so, if you know how to solve it.I'm very frustrated about this.

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace

Comment: I’m facing the same issue. please help me here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577207/spring-boot-deployed-in-lambda-throws-nosuchmethoderror

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

AWS labs (an Amazon affiliated project) has an open source library "aws-serverless-java-container" that does exactly what you want! It supports Spring, Spring Boot, Spark, Jersey, Struts, and other popular frameworks, and is a very thin wrapper over your existing application.  In a nutshell, you exclude embedded tomcat from your dependencies, and package your jar using maven shade (instead of creating an executable jar via the spring boot maven plugin, and define a LambdaHandler where you configure basically tell the library what your main class is, and whether or not it is a reactive or webmvc app, and some other configurations (like what request shape to use (e.g, ApiGateway v1, v2, etc) and library does the rest. It's great but Spring is not the best framework for this use case due to its long startup times due to the way Spring boot uses reflection to try and guess what your application configuration should be (based on dependencies on your classpath, etc) (if latency is an issue for you). But the good news is soon Spring 3 will support graalvm, and maybe functional bean registration so startup times should dramatically improve in the coming years. When I've had to use this library in production I've found that using Spring over Spring Boot or disabling auto configuration and explicitly configuring the context manually resulted in better startup times, as did removing all unnecessary dependencies from the classpath.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot2

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this library: https://github.com/MelonProjectCom/lambda-http-router

It works like standard Controller.

```
 @PathPostMapping("/example/test")
 public String example(@Body String body) {
    return "Hello World! - body: " + body;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows the wrong package name for your class.

It should be

`pryce_pick.search.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest`

Comment: That's surely not the problem I wrote 'mypackage' as something general to represent a package, when its not 'mypackage' I just forgot to replace it.

Comment: It won't work if it's incorrect. So if it's just a mistake in the screenshot you probably want to correct it so others can help you.

Comment: Changed it. I hope there is no more typos. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MarkSailes I’m facing the same issue. I am trying to deploy my simple (which has 2 end points) spring boot service into lambda. I am facing issue after deploying in lambda. Pls help me. As it’s high priority for me to immediately complete for my company. I am already too late.

I explained the issue in detail here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577207/spring-boot-deployed-in-lambda-throws-nosuchmethoderror

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use register Function Bean which will work as a Lambda and supports all Spring Boot features.

Create a Function with @Bean annotation

```java
@Bean
public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
  return value -> {
      return value.toUpperCase();
  };
}
```

By default, this Bean will work as Lambda.

You also need to add `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleReques` as handler in AWS Lambda.

If you want to use the same codebase with multiple `Bean` `Function` as Lambda then you can conditionally enable `Bean` as follows:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="active.lambda", havingValue="MyLambdaOne")
public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
  return value -> {
      return value.toUpperCase();
  };
}
```

**Reference:**

[Official Spring Doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_aws_lambda)

[Spring GitHub Repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-aws)

[Serverless.com Article](https://www.serverless.com/examples/aws-java-spring-cloud-function-demo)

#### Another way to do this (Not tested)

This can also be achieved as mentioned [here](https://dzone.com/articles/run-code-with-spring-cloud-function-on-aws-lambda). [Not Tested]